# Can quinoa be grown in the UK?

Tags: optimal-conditions, native-conditions

Due to the fact that quinoa, bought in shops here, cost a lot and because of the [ethical implications of buying quinoa](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2013/jan/16/vegans-stomach-unpalatable-truth-quinoa) (and also just for the hell of it), I'd like to know if it's possible to grow quinoa in the UK?

If it is possible, what are the ideal conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quinoa, unlike Amaranth, likes cool summers, so it should grow fine in the UK.  There are some new selections that are bred to grow in the Pacific Northwest of the United States, which is a maritime climate similar to much of the UK.  You should start it about now, direct sowing where it is to grow, then thin to the desired spacing after it's well up and growing.  It likes loamy soil in full sun with a neutral pH.

Some [cultivation information for Quinoa](http://www.westcoastseeds.com/how-to-grow/Vegetable-Seeds/Quinoa/)...

Here are [some varieties currently being grown or tested in the PNW](http://www.westcoastseeds.com/product/Vegetable-Seeds/Quinoa/#sthash.LRyKH7ME.dpbs). We will be growing Brightest Brilliant Quinoa this coming season here in western Washington state.

Answer (score 3):

The Real Seed Catalogue (online) sells quinoa seeds of various types for growing in the UK - they need to be started off in trays or pots I think, but they give you instructions. I'm assuming you only want small scale growing in your garden or allotment.